# Word Automation - now complains of "File In Use" locked for editing by 'another user'

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-access-2010, office-automation

I have an MsAccess form which utilised Word automation to create Patient clinical letters.

For some reason this has stopped working successfully all of a sudden.

Instead Word pops up a dialog behind the access application (found by ALT-Tab):

[image: Error Dialog]

Basically the automation works like this

1. Choose an existing letter from database list (e.g previous letter for current patient)
2. Check it exists in the Letter directory (as the database has the location in it only)
3. Copy the letter to the Drafts directory under a new name:

   FNAME, Lastname (URN) - usernamecreate-usernamefor-DOCUMENTID - YYYY-MM-DD.doc
4. Open the Document in Word
5. Replace the Date with current, replace the Signature with "usernamefor" signature
6. Bring Word to the foreground ready for modifications

It is now stopping after (4.) with that dialog above.

---

If you choose:

(x) Create a local copy and merge your changes later

about 4-10 seconds later it detects the original is available and we are able to proceed etc.

Thoughts?

How to detect who/what/how is accessing the file?

---

I have since run with Process Monitor running and filtering for events on the \share drive. I have dumped the following details for WINWORD.EXE which may be relevant for a FAILED open:

```
 CreateFile SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
 CreateFile SHARING VIOLATION   Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a
 CreateFile SUCCESS           Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
```

Answer (score 0):

In a command prompt

```
openfiles /local on
```

reboot

```
openfiles /query
```

Comment: Didn't help as shows only ACCESS, EXPLORER and WINWORD opening the file.

I have now rug PROCESS MONITOR (from Microsoft SystemInternals) utility to Filter on what is going on with that file. Results in below answer.

Comment: Looking forward to your post.

Comment: Post your code, access shouldn't have the file opened.

Comment: An application can also use CreateFile to specify whether it wants to share the file for reading, writing, both, or neither. This is known as the sharing mode. An open file that is not shared cannot be opened again, either by the application that opened it or by another application, until its handle has been closed.

Comment: When a process attempts to open a file that has already been opened in sharing mode, the system compares the requested access and sharing modes to those specified when the file was opened. If you specify an access mode that conflicts with the sharing mode specified in the previous open call, CreateFile fails with a sharing violation (ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION). If you specify a sharing mode that conflicts with the access mode specified in the previous open call, CreateFile fails with a sharing violation.